# How to format datetime in a dataframe the way I want?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I cannot find the correct format for this datetime. I have tried several formats, `%Y/%m/%d%I:%M:%S%p` is the closest format I can find for the example below.

```
df['datetime'] = '2019-11-13 16:28:05.779'

df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'], format="%Y/%m/%d%I:%M:%S%p")
```

Result:

```
ValueError: time data '2019-11-13 16:28:05.779' does not match format '%Y/%m/%d%I:%M:%S%p' (match)
```

Comment: Did you look at the documentation for format strings/codes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before guessing yourself have pandas make the first guess

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'], infer_datetime_format=True)
0   2019-11-13 16:28:05.779
Name: datetime, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can solve this probably by using the parameter `infer_datetime_format=True`. Here's an example:

```
df = {}
df['datetime'] = '2019-11-13 16:28:05.779'
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'], infer_datetime_format=True)
print(df['datetime'])
print(type(df['datetime'])
```

Output:

```
2019-11-13 16:28:05.779000
<class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the `pandas.to_datetime()` call with the correct format string: `pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'], format="%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")`

You were missing a space, `%I` is for 12-hour time (the example time you gave is `16:28`, and `%p` is, to quote the docs, the *Locale’s equivalent of either AM or PM.*